# Compute mean of columns for groups of rows in Octave

Tags: matrix, octave, mean

I have a matrix, for example:

```
1 2
3 4
4 5
```

And I also have a rule of grouping the rows, which is defined as a vector of group IDs like this:

```
1
2
1
```

Which means that the first and the third rows belong to the same group (ID 1) and the second row belong to another group (ID 2). So, I would like to compute the mean value for each group. Here is the result for my example:

```
2.5 3.5
3 4
```

More formally, there is a matrix **A** of size (**m**, **n**), a number of groups **k** and a vector **v** of size (**m**, 1), values of which are integers in range from 1 to **k**. The result is a matrix **R** of size (**k**, **n**), where each row with index **r** corresponds to the mean value of the group **r**.

Here is my solution (which does what I need) using for-loop in Octave:

```
R = zeros(k, n);
for r = 1:k
    R(r, :) = mean(A((v == r), :), 1);
end
```

I wonder whether it could be vectorized. So, what I need is to replace the for-loop with a vectorized solution, which is going to be much more efficient than the iterative one.

Here is one of my many attempts (which do not work) to solve the problem in a vectorized way:

```
R = mean(A((v == 1:k), :);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider it as a matrix multiplication problem. For instance, for your example this corresponds to

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 4 5];
B = [0.5,0,0.5;0,1,0];

C = B*A
```

The main issue, is to construct `B` from your list of indicies in an efficient manner. My suggestion is to use the implicit expansion of `==`.

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 4 5]; % Input data
idx = [1;2;1]; % Input Grouping

k = 2; % number of groups, ( = max(idx) )
m = 3; % Number of "observations"
Btmp = (idx == 1:k)'; % Mark locations
B = Btmp ./sum(Btmp,2); % Normalise
C = B*A

C =

    2.5000    3.5000
    3.0000    4.0000
```

Comment: It seems like Btmp could be constructed more easily: (idx == 1:k)'. Automatic broadcasting operation is applied here, so repmat is unnecessary.

Comment: @IhorDobrovolskyi, Right, I keep forgetting that, is a thing now. Do you by any chance remember whether there is any speedup?

Comment: I do not think that there is any reasonable speedup, however it should save some memory.

Comment: And having more readable code is also a good reason to use automatic broadcasting, so I always prefer that way.

Answer (score 2):

As long as our data is of floating point, you can just do it manually by doing the sum yourself and then divide, by making use of `accumdim`. Like so:

```
octave:1> A = [1 2; 3 4; 4 5];
octave:2> subs = [1; 2; 1];
octave:3> accumdim (subs, A) ./ accumdim (subs, ones (rows (subs), 1))
ans =

   2.5000   3.5000
   3.0000   4.0000
```

Comment: I did not know about accumdim. It seems like that is the function I was searching for. Thank you for pointing to it.

Comment: Don't you know whether it is more efficient than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61840377/7269381) answer? Honestly saying, the solution with accumdim is less readable, so the only reason I would prefer it is the efficiency.

Comment: @IhorDobrovolskyi other reasons are 1) less memory usage and 2) works in older versions of Octave (which I found very common in HPC). Also, `accumdim` and `accumarray` (a more complex but more flexible version of `accumdim`) are (were) the typical answers for this type of question and seems pretty readable to me. I guess readability is relative, probably on how used you are to these functions vs automatic broadcasting.